# 'Controller' is namespace but is used like a type-- ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I am facing a strange error in Visual Studio 2019 Community edition when I add a new controller to my application, it throws:

> 'Controller' is namespace but is used like a type error

What I did so far

1. cleaned/rebuild the project
2. restarted Visual Studio / computer as well
3. shuffled the namespaces

But when I remove the controller and re-build my application again it succeeds, not sure why IntelliSense causing this error, I have all the necessary namespace added to it

Please see this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You named your own namespace `Controller`. The tooltip shows exactly this - that `Controller` is the namespace `FirstCoreApplication.Controller`

Comment: yep, thanks guys :) I didn't notice that we always need another pair of eyes